# How can i pass ng-model using query string in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, query-string

I am using angularjs to make a form with few fields. For some purpose I want to use query string to the pass the form values. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24routeParams).
well, I thought they have better example in the past. Look at [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/) one.